# What is proper way to check if List<MyClass> contain copy of some MyClass object?

Tags: c#, oop

I have pretty complex structure:

```
public static List<state> states = new List<state>();
public class state : List<situation> { }
public class situation {
    //public rule rule; //another complex object
    public int pos;
    public string term;

    public situation(/*rule rule,*/ string terminal, int pointPosition) {
        //this.rule = rule;
        this.term = terminal;
        this.pos  = pointPosition;
    }
}
```

In my program i generate new `state` objects what must be added to `states` list. But only if here is no same `state` in this list (order of `situation` objects in `state` list is don't matter and can be different in two `state` what is equal in fact).

I tryed this:

```
states.Add(new state());
states[0].Add(new situation("#", 0));

state s = new state();
s.Add(new situation("#", 0));

if (states.Contains(s)) {
    Console.WriteLine("HODOR"); //not performed
}
```

Looks like `Contains` don't work right with custom objects, so i must create some custom method.

I can just compare each objects and each fields but... it's look like pretty tedious and ugly solution. May be here is some better way to do this?

Comment: Well, `Contains` will use `Equals` to check for equality. The *first* things I'd do would be to fix your names to follow normal naming conventions, ideally use composition rather than inheritance for `State`, and then make your fields private. Then read up on how to implement `IEquatable<T>`, and implement it for both `State` and `Situation`.

Comment: As Jon said, implementing Equals method will work for you. Contains will return false because by default it compares two objects are same not their values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `Equals` in your situation class and implement your own equality i.e :

```
public class situation 
{
      public string Terminal 
      {
         get{ return term;}
      }

      public int Pos
      {
         get{ return pos;}
      }

      public override bool Equals(object obj)
      {
         bool result;
         situation s = obj as situation;
         if (s != null)
         {
            result = Terminal.Equals(s.Terminal) && Pos == s.Pos;
         }

         return result;
      }
}
```

Comment: What is `if (situation != null)`? You mean `if (s != null)`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also added this:

```
public class state : List<situation> {

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        state s = obj as state;
        if (s != null) {
            foreach (situation situation in s) {
                if (!this.Contains(situation)) { return false; }
            }

            foreach (situation situation in this) {
                if (!s.Contains(situation)) { return false; }
            }

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

So my example works.